# ReCaptcha on Laravel

Tags: laravel, recaptcha

I have ReCaptcha in Register controller and I wanted to put it in the login controller here like

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Rules\Captcha;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use App\Rules\Captcha;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'g-recaptcha-response' => new Captcha(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

But Im getting an error `Cannot use App\Rules\Captcha as Captcha because the name is already in use`
Is there other ways to put ReCaptcha in the reg and log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line twice at the start of your file:

```
use App\Rules\Captcha;
```

Comment: wtf how I haven't notice